# Filter by serialized attribute using ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

I'm using ActiveAdmin and I need to build a custom filter, a combobox with abilities to filter users index list. For example:

```
<select>
   <option value="designer">Diseñador</option>
   <option value="developer">Desarrollador</option>
   <option value="manager">Jefe de Proyecto</option>
</select>
```

I have users...

```
#<User id: 1, email: "un@tipo.com", abilities: {"designer"=>"Some comment", "developer"=>"Other comment", "manager"=>"Another comment"}>
#<User id: 2, email: "otro@tipo.com", abilities: {"designer"=>"blah blah"}>
```

As you can see, **abilities attribute** is defined on **User model** as:

```
serialize :abilities, Hash
```

So, when in the combobox I select **designer** I want to see **two users** on the list.
If instead I choose **manager** I want to see **one user**.

I know that ActiveAdmin uses [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) to build filters but I don't know how to use this to work with serialized attributes.

I tried to use [ransacker](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/36) with the following code:

**ActiveAdmin**:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do  
  filter :by_ability, as: :string, collection: ['designer', 'other']
```

**Model**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_ability_eq, lambda {|v| User.where(["users.abilities LIKE '%?%'", v]) }
  ransacker :by_ability_eq
```

**but I get this error**:

```
undefined method `by_ability_eq' for Ransack::Search<class: User, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do  
  filter :abilities_contains, as: :select, collection: ['designer', 'other']
  #....
end
```

In this case you don't need scope in model

**UPD**

IF you need only keys to search, and your serializator uses YAML, you can try to customize it with something like

```
collection:  [["designer", "designer:"], ["other","other:"]]
```

Than it will use "designer:" and "other:" to search with LIKE

Comment: What if you have this: `#<User id: 1, email: "un@tipo.com", abilities: {"designer"=>"Some comment", "developer"=>"Other comment", "manager"=>"Another comment"}>
#<User id: 2, email: "otro@tipo.com", abilities: {"designer"=>"I'm designer and developer too"}>` If you choose *developer* option from drop down list, you will get two rows instead one. Because that *contains* will check on key and values too (the whole string).

Comment: @Leantraxxx, your scope by_ability_eq is doing the same, isn't it ?

Comment: my scope didn't work. On the other hand, I "solved" my problem just like you did, but still being a workaround. So +1 for the answer but It's no the one I need.

Comment: @Leantraxxx, please attach examples of raw data that you have in your abilities column

Comment: stored on db: `--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
art_director: Soy un director de arte desde hace 5 años
animation: Más que nada usando flash
ui_ux_designer: Tengo 3 años de expriencia en este campo
web_developer: uso Ionic para desarrollar sitios mobile`. From rails console: `abilities: {"art_director"=>"Soy un director de arte desde hace 5 años", "animation"=>"Más que nada usando flash", "ui_ux_designer"=>"Tengo 3 años de expriencia en este campo", "web_developer"=>"uso Ionic para desarrollar sitios mobile"}` hash values can be anything since I'm storing user comments.